# Geweke diagnostic of a Markov chain: why does the first window have to cover the burn-in?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, diagnostic

I read the following statement in this [document](http://people.su.se/~sehh3288/documents/students/Master%20Thesis%20-%20Kristoffer%20Sahlin%20-%20final.pdf)$^{[1]}$, at the bottom of page 11:

> Too wide A will some times “hide” the burn in part within the converged part of the chain and the difference in means may not be large enough for the diagnostic to give an indication of non convergence.

where A is the first window in Geweke diagnostic. Geweke statistic is defined as:

$$Z_n=\frac{(\bar \theta_A - \bar \theta_B)}{\sqrt{\hat S_\theta^A(0)/n_A+\hat S_\theta^B(0)/n_B}}$$

where $A$ and $B$ refers to the first window and second window respectively, $\bar \theta$ is the mean value, $\hat S_\theta(0)$ is spectrum density, $n$ is the number of data points.

What I don't understand here is: since this quantity should converge to $N(0,1)$ if the two intervals have the same distribution, why does interval A have to cover the burn-in to give an indication of non-convergence?

[1] Sahlin, Kristoffer (2011),
'*Estimating convergence of Markov chain Monte Carlo simulations*',
Masters thesis, Stockholms universitet, Stockholm

Comment: You should give a full reference for your link. Links can disappear. You should also mention the page number that your quote is taken from.

Comment: @Glen_b I didn't see any reference I can use for this article. Do you have any idea of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the idea is that if there's been convergence, we could tell the initial burn-in period from the stationary distribution.

If you take the initial period too long - e.g. much wider than the actual period it takes to effectively be sampling from the stationary distribution - then your initial period statistics will be a mixture consisting mostly of sampling the stationary distribution and may not look different from a sample of the stationary distribution only.

Comment: If I understand correctly, if the first window is large enough to bury the burn-in, it is still feasible to use Geweke diagnostic to tell whether the chain has converged, but cannot tell how long the initial burn-in period is? In other words, if I don't care about the burn-in period, it doesn't matter if I choose a large first window?

Comment: Problem solved here -- I simply misunderstood the fact that the diagnostic is to test the convergence of the whole selected range, not the window B. Thanks for your answer!